# Combo box not displaying bound values in Silverlight Xaml

Tags: silverlight, xaml

Hi I am very new to silverlight when i tried to bind a combobox, there are 3 Items in the ItemsSource and  DisplayMemberPath as the  "JobName" but the values are not getting binded.
 Here is my code below. 
xaml:

```
 <combobox x:name="cbJobName" grid.column="1" grid.row="1" margin="5,5,0,10"                                         horizontalalignment="Left" style="{StaticResource ComboBoxStyle2}"  width="200" maxwidth="250" height="23" maxdropdownheight="250" tooltipservice.tooltip="Select a Job" selectionchanged="cbJobName_SelectionChanged">
    </combobox>
```

**Code Behind:**

```
            JobNames = new List<JobList>();

            JobList Jobs = new JobList();
            Jobs.jobID = 1; 
            Jobs.jobName = "DM Propagation";
            Jobs.errorMessage = "";
            Jobs.lastDate = "1/11/2014";
            Jobs.nextDate = "2/11/2014";
            Jobs.jobState = 1;
            JobNames.Add(Jobs);

            Jobs = new JobList();
            Jobs.jobID = 2;
            Jobs.jobName = "Import Propagation"; 
            Jobs.errorMessage = "";
            Jobs.jobState = 2;
            Jobs.lastDate = "3/11/2014";
            Jobs.nextDate = "4/11/2014";
            JobNames.Add(Jobs);

            Jobs = new JobList();
            Jobs.jobID = 3;
            Jobs.jobName = "Cross Propagation";
            Jobs.errorMessage = "";
            Jobs.jobState = 2; 
            Jobs.lastDate = "5/11/2014";
            Jobs.nextDate = "6/11/2014";
            JobNames.Add(Jobs);

              cbJobName.ItemsSource = JobNames;
              cbJobName.DisplayMemberPath = "jobName";
              cbJobName.SelectedIndex = 0;
              biJobProcessingHome.IsBusy = false;
```

Comment: use JobNames = new List(of JobList ) instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have made a mistake while making list, here you go,

in xaml,

```
 <ComboBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="188,150,0,0" Name="comboBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />
```

lets say you have a class named Job,

```
public class Job
{
    public int JobID { get; set; }
    public string jobName { get; set; }
    public string errorMessage { get; set; }
    public DateTime lastDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime nextDate { get; set; }
    public int status { get; set; }
}
```

this how you bind it,

```
  List<Job> JobsList = new List<Job>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                Job jobObj = new Job();
                jobObj.JobID = i;
                jobObj.jobName = "test" + i;
                jobObj.status = 1;
                jobObj.errorMessage = "success";
                JobsList.Add(jobObj);

            }
            comboBox1.ItemsSource = JobsList;
            comboBox1.DisplayMemberPath = "jobName";
```

Comment: Thank you!! Thank You!! I was missing the get set methods for my properties in my class *blush* Thank you!

Comment: can you please mark it as an answer if it has helped you!